# Studio 12.3: language optional software package not installed

Tags: solaris

I installed the Solaris Studio 12.3 on Solaris 10 OS but when I check the version but it is showing below result. It is installed under `/opt/SolarisStudio12.3/bin` so why wrong path is coming. I defined the path in `.profile` after that I can see now the correct path when I check `$PATH` `/opt/SolarisStudio12.3/bin` but still it is showing same path for which `cc` and `cc -V` as below. Can anyone please tell me?

```
which cc
/usr/ucb/cc

cc -V
/usr/ucb/cc: language optional software package not installed
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `/usr/ucb/cc` is probably a script that checks if `/usr/ccs/bin/ucbcc` is installed and then invokes it (or complains if not there, like in your case).

`/usr/ccs/bin/ucbcc` is part of the package unbundled C compiler, `SPROcc`. You are probably missing that.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the /usr/ccs/bin/ucbcc folder is exist but don't know how check. can you please tell me.

Comment: I have no access to a SunOS system at the moment, so it is difficult to hand-hold.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `/opt/SolarisStudio12.3/bin/cc` and never `/usr/ucb/cc` - the ucb script is an old compatibility wrapper for building SunOS 4 software that doesn't work with current Studio releases and was deleted from Solaris 11 and later.

Simplest is to ensure that `/opt/SolarisStudio12.3/bin` is in your `$PATH` environment variable ahead of `/usr/ucb`.